# XMLHttpRequest for JSON file works perfectly in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, google-chrome, userscripts

I've narrowed my problem area down to the function below. It's part of a userscript I'm writing. It works perfectly in Chrome, but doesn't work at all in Firefox/Greasemonkey. I've tinkered with it all day and have hit a brick wall. The only thing that makes sense is if JSON.parse isn't working right, which would make sense since Chrome is known to handle JSON.parse somewhat differently... but I know the JSON is perfectly formed!

```
function getTagline() {
    var jsonfile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    jsonfile.open("GET", "http://example.com/somegood.json", true);
    jsonfile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (jsonfile.readyState == 4) {
            if (jsonfile.status == 200) {
                var taglines = JSON.parse(jsonfile.responseText);
                var choose = Math.floor(Math.random() * taglines.length);
                var tagline = document.createTextNode(taglines[choose].metais);
                insertTagline(tagline);
            }
        }
    };
    jsonfile.send(null);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post part of the JSON you are trying to parse?

Comment: Here's an example: [{"commenturl": ["/107669/Solutionism-is-the-new-Optimism#3934686"], "metais": ["Metafilter: took the day off and sat in the basement in the dark and didn't really respond to anything at all"], "user": ["uncanny hengeman"]},{"commenturl": ["/107126/Lancelot-Link-Secret-Chimp#3905976"], "metais": ["Metafilter:  They're not monkeys.  They're pedants."], "user": ["Daddy-O"]},
{"commenturl": ["/107129/My-job-is-to-watch-dreams-die#3906426"], "metais": ["MetaFilter: mostly terrible people hiding behind good links"], "user": ["Faint of Butt"]}]

Comment: So, it's a list of objects. It should be valid, according to JSON.org. I think... :P

Comment: Works fine for me, but have to escape the single quotes in Firebug (\'). http://o7.no/nJ2nJA

Comment: Does that script reach the JSON.parse line?  If so, does that call throw, and if so, what exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more troubleshooting, it turns out the was a cross-domain XHR issue. It was working in Chrome because, by default, Chrome was allowing the script on all domains. I tweaked the headers so Chrome knew to only allow the proper domains, but Firefox disallows cross-domain on XHR regardless. This was fixed by simply switching to GM_xmlhttpRequest instead, which allows cross-domain in Firefox and, thankfully, which Chrome also supports.

Thanks for the help, folks!

Answer (score 1):

I was told that JSON is not supported without an extra library, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535724/why-do-i-get-an-extra-element-at-the-end-in-json) the accepted answer. I also tried this

```
try {
    clientList = JSON.parse(responseText);
} catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
}
```

And the message I get is "JSON is undefined". So the answer seems correct.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a try tomorrow. [This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON) made me think it was supported, though... I'll comment again after I've tried it.

Comment: Hm, looks like that's not it... switched to using eval for that line, to test. It still works fine in Chrome, using eval, but no go in Firefox.